# How to go about creating a 'Song list' view for a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently trying to get my head around WPF,
how would I go about creating a view consisting of a list of songs, sortable by various properties of the songs, (i.e. Artist, Title...)
Was using a ListBox, but with little success.
Thanks

Comment: You'll have to provide us with more explanation of your goal, code you've tried, what exactly is not working, and so on...

Comment: show us your little success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand better choice for you will be `DataGrid` it offers built-in sorting (Atrist, Title etc.)

```
    <DataGrid Name="Songs" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding SongList}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Artist"  Binding="{Binding Artist}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```